# How to send data from the elements with a class selected

Tags: javascript, php, get

Example of problem:

I have html:

```
<form action="GET">
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2000</button>
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2001</button>
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2002</button>
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2003</button>
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2004</button>
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2005</button>
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2006</button>
  <button onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')">2007</button>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and part of the sample database:

```
year  |  title  |  ...
2000  |  film1
2000  |  film2
2002  |  film3
2001  |  film4
....  |  .....
```

I need to search the database records based on selected fields.

Comment: Where is your `code for search` which you tried from your end ?

Comment: give your buttons a `name` attribute, perhaps change them to `inputs` of type=button

Comment: why does your form's `action` attribute have "GET"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just do that with a class. When sending a form, you have to make sure the right `input` elements with the `name` attributes are sent. What I would do is remove the inline JS and add to the toggle class to disable/enable a corresponding input. Try this out:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <button type="button">
        2000
        <input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="2000" disabled>
    </button>

    <button type="button">
        2001
        <input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="2001" disabled>
    </button>

    <button type="button">
        2002
        <input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="2002" disabled>
    </button>

    <button type="button">
        2003
        <input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="2003" disabled>
    </button>

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>


<script>
    $('button').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').promise().done(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).find('input').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $(this).find('input').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

your `submit.php` will have results like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'options' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2000' (length=4)
      1 => string '2002' (length=4)
```